# Hiding spinner buttons for a specific Jquery UI spinner

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, spinner, readonly-attribute

I have a readonly JQuery UI spinner and I want to disable or hide the spinning buttons.

I saw from a previous question, that if I want to hide all spinner buttons I can use:

```
$('.ui-spinner .ui-spinner-button').css('display','none');
```

and it work great.

But how do I filter just one specific element?

I have tried

```
$('#specifcElement a.ui-spinner-button').css('display','none');
```

and also

```
$('.ui-spinner specificElement.ui-spinner-button').css('display','none')
```

without succes.

Comment: Your selector works or the style itsn't applyed ?

Comment: Style is not applied, selector is read only but the spinners buttons are not hided and working.

Comment: Try another jQuery method like .addClass(). Define a .hidden class on you stylesheet with display:none and use $('.ui-spinner specificElement.ui-spinner-button').addClass('hidden');

Comment: Thank you, I did, spinner buttons are still there.   
I have defined .hidden {
    display: none;
} and I have  used  $('.ui-spinner #specificElement.ui-spinner-button').addClass('hidden'); or $('.ui-spinner specificElement.ui-spinner-button').addClass('hidden'). 
No joy!

Comment: So this is not a jQuery question, you have an CSS problem. To help you is needed more information. Can you edit the question and post your stylesheet ? Maybe this could help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663712/css-display-none-not-working

Comment: @VitorPiovezam Thank you sir, but I don't think is a style sheet problem, because if i put $('#specificElement').addClass('hidden'); it hides the whole spinner element .....

Comment: @VitorPiovezam , also if I do $('.ui-spinner .ui-spinner-button').addClass('hidden'); it will also work - it will hide ALL spinner buttons- it just don't work for a single element .... anyway thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spinner wraps the element upon initialization and it appears like so:

```
<span class="ui-spinner ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content" style="display: none;">
  <input id="spinner" name="value" class="spin ui-spinner-input" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton">
  <a tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button-icon-only" role="button">
    <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>
  </a>
  <a tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button-icon-only" role="button">
    <span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>
  </a>
</span>
```

So to hide the spinner objects we can select the text field and then select it's Parent element.

Consider the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".spin").spinner();

  $("#spinner-2").parent().add("label[for=spinner-2]").hide();
});
```

```css
.spin-wrap {
  width: 340px;
}

.spin-wrap .ui-spinner {
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="spin-wrap">
  <label for="spinner-1">Select value 1:</label>
  <input id="spinner-1" name="value[1]" class="spin">
  <label for="spinner-2">Select value 2:</label>
  <input id="spinner-2" name="value[2]" class="spin">
  <label for="spinner-3">Select value 3:</label>
  <input id="spinner-3" name="value[3]" class="spin">
</div>
```

Here you can see that `$("#spinner-2")` is just selecting the `input` element. I then used `.parent()` to select the spinner itself. I also used `.add()` to add the `label` element to the object so it is hidden too.